# Selecionar valores extremos de um determinado intervalo no MySQL

Tags: mysql

Preciso coletar apenas os valores extremos de 'id' para cada faixa horária dada. Conforme os dados abaixo, preciso coletar os id's 63 e 67 para a hora de 00:45:22, 80 e 84 para a hora de 01:15:26. Como proceder?

```
id   n  hora          data      AP

63  5   00:45:22    24/05/2017  3  
64  5   00:45:22    24/05/2017  1  
65  5   00:45:22    24/05/2017  3  
66  5   00:45:22    24/05/2017  3  
67  5   00:45:22    24/05/2017  3  
80  5   01:15:26    24/05/2017  5  
81  5   01:15:26    24/05/2017  5  
82  5   01:15:26    24/05/2017  5  
83  5   01:15:26    24/05/2017  5  
84  5   01:15:26    24/05/2017  5
```

Comment: `AP` ou `N` influencia na resposta esperada?

Comment: Sim Jefferson, preciso obter uma seleção final que me forneça os APs de cada id, tanto máximo, quanto mínimo. Entretanto, para o que perguntei a resposta do Motta é suficiente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAX e GROUP BY

```
select hora , min(id) min_id , max(id) max_id
from tabela
group by hora
```

O  GROUP BY é usado quando se quer usar agregadores como soma , contagem , média , desvio padrão , máximo e mínimos , pode ser usado também para a eliminação de duplicados , sempre recomendo uma leitura na documentação do fornecedor do SGBD para detalhes.

Comment: Motta, tem como explicar melhor o que cada função faz? Principalmente o `group by`. Aliás, é necessário pegar o `id` mínimo também.

Comment: http://www.devmedia.com.br/exemplos-com-group-by-e-com-a-clausula-having-totalizando-dados-sql-server-2008-parte-2/19839  veja link para uso do group by ..   O mínimo foi editado na resposta ,

Comment: Motta, o objetivo do site é gerar conteúdo de qualidade que sirva de referência para outras pessoas, não apenas solucionar um problema particular. Então o ideal é que você coloque pelo menos a explicação mínima do que seu código faz na resposta, sem depender de links. Obviamente que é interessante você também citar a referência oficial caso a pessoa queira estender a pesquisa.